# How to dynamically return the column range (Sheet1!D:D) that contains a specific header

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet that I'm trying to error proof and rather than hard code a column in my `index`/ `match`, I'd like to dynmically reference the location of that column based on the column header. Is there's a more efficient way to accomplish this than my current solution which is:

```
INDIRECT("MasterSheet!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C$3,MasterSheet!$4:$4,0),4),"1","")
 &":"& SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C$3,MasterSheet!$4:$4,0),4),"1",""))
```

Comment: `=INDEX(A:XFD,0,MATCH(C$3,MasterSheet!$4:$4,0))` will return the full column.

Comment: that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottCraner If that worked, and it seems like it did, you should post a full answer based on that comment so you can get credit for the answer.